# Die Bedeutung des Ausdruckes " Bananen voll wie auf Oliver Kahn schmeissen"

Tags: idiom

> Und sollte ich erfahren, ich rap prollig und arm 
>   `schmeiß ich voll die Bananen wie auf Olliver Kahn`.

Was bedeutet dieser Ausdruck?

Ich habe diese Redewendung nicht in meinem Wörterbuch gefunden. Könnte mir jemand sagen, was dieser Ausdruck ist?

Comment: Der ganze Text dieses Songs (»König von Deutschland« von Eko Fresh) ist voll mit Anspielungen auf Prominente aus Deutschland, von denen ich viele nicht kenne. (Ich bin aber auch kein Deutscher sondern Österreicher und gehöre mit 50 Jahren auch nicht zur Zielgruppe von Rappern.) Ich glaube Olliver Kahn ist ein Fußballspieler oder Fußballtrainer, und ich vermute mal, dass er mal mit Bananen beworfen wurde. Warum und von wem wird dir sicher Google sagen wenn du die richtigen Fragen stellst. Im Übrigen ist anzumerken, dass Rap-Texte keine gute Textsorte sind um Deutsch zu lernen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es ist keine feststehende Redewendung, und Rapper sind auch nicht gerade für ihr stilsicheres und makelloses Deutsch bekannt. Offenbar wird hier aber auf Oliver Kahn angespielt, *der während seiner Vereinskarriere des Öfteren von gegnerischen Fans mit Bananen beworfen [wurde], um ihn wegen seiner angeblichen Ähnlichkeit mit einem Gorilla zu verspotten.* ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Kahn))